# Как учесть скроллинг, когда при наведении мыши отображаю второй элемент вплотную к первому?

Tags: html, css

При наведении курсора мышки должны отобразиться кнопки. Но как сделать так, чтобы они были всегда, например, под правым нижним углом 1-го элемента? С учетом того, что координаты едут при скроллинге. Пробовал следующие координаты мыши из `event`:
`clientX`, 
`target.offsetLeft`,
`screenX`,
`pageX`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPD. Отредактировал заголовок вопроса и понял, что мой ответ не годится.

Без скроллинга можно так:

1. При наведении курсора jQuery добавляет в блок кнопку. При уходе курсора - удаляет.
2. Вместе с кнопкой добавляем и обработчик для нажатия на неё. Если селектор `$('.button-alert')` вынести за пределы функции, то он отработает до того, как кнопка добавится в DOM, и при нажатии на кнопку ничего не произойдёт.
3. Чтобы положение кнопки рассчитывалось [относительно краёв её родителя](https://webref.ru/css/position#field_css_value), блокам задано относительное позиционирование, а кнопкам - абсолютное.
4. "Под правым нижним углом" - это `right: 0; top: 100%;`. Если понадобится "в правом нижнем углу", то надо заменить на `right: 0; bottom: 0;`

Но если у блока появляется скроллинг, то такая кнопка:

1. оказывается накрыта скроллингом
2. при скроллировании перемещается вместе с остальным содержимым блока.

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/Lo276ban/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $( '.content' ).hover(
    function() {
      $( this ).append( '<button type="button" class="button-alert">Click</button>' );
      $( '.button-alert' ).click(function() {
        alert( 'This is block ' + $( this ).parent().attr( 'id' ));
      });
  }, function() {
      $( this ).find( '.button-alert' ).remove();
    }
  );
});
```

```css
/* heart of the matter */
.button-alert {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0%;
  top: 100%;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
}
#C { overflow: scroll; }

/* nice look */
.content {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  padding: 0 2px;
}
#A { height: 20px; width: 100%; }
#B { height: 40px; width: 60%; }
#C { height: 80px; width: 20%; }
```

```html
<div id="A" class="content">A</div>
<div id="B" class="content">B</div>
<div id="C" class="content">C <br>C <br>C <br>C <br>C <br>C</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Оставляю свой ответ, как [минимальный рабочий пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) к вопросу.

Comment: Обернуть ещё одним дивом и не мучаться.

Comment: @Discord Оборачивая блок, приходится проверить его, как минимум, на `inline-block`, `float` и `margin-right`. Иначе можно промахнуться с положением кнопки и/или изменить поведение самого блока. Получается хлопотно. [Решение Qwertiy](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/529285/208926) проще и универсальнее.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так, но следует проверить (и/или улучшить) кроссбраузерность.

```js
$('.button-alert').click(function() {
  alert('This is block ' + $(this).data('dest'));
});

~function () {
  var id;

  $('.content').hover(function () {
    var rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    clearTimeout(id);
    $('.button-alert').data('dest', this.id).css({left: window.scrollX + rect.right, top: window.scrollY + rect.bottom}).show();
  }, function () {
    id = setTimeout(function () {
      $('.button-alert').hide();
    }, 1000);
  });
  
}();
```

```css
html, body { /* force scrolls */
  margin: 1em 0 0 1em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.button-alert {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}

.button-alert:hover {
  display: block !important;
}

#C { overflow: scroll; }

/* nice look */
.content {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  padding: 0 2px;
}

#A { height: 20px; width: 100%; }
#B { height: 40px; width: 60%; }
#C { height: 80px; width: 20%; }
```

```html
<div id="A" class="content">A</div>
<div id="B" class="content">B</div>
<div id="C" class="content">C <br>C <br>C <br>C <br>C <br>C</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" hidden class="button-alert">Click</button>
```